# From 12 entries take max from predetermint group of entries and change a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table. The table contains of 20 columns. But only 3 of them are important for the question. It looks like this:

[image: Table Value]

You can create it with this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   AssesmentID INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,CategoryID  INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Value       INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(AssesmentID,CategoryID,Value) VALUES (478366,1,62);
INSERT INTO mytable(AssesmentID,CategoryID,Value) VALUES (478366,2,30);
INSERT INTO mytable(AssesmentID,CategoryID,Value) VALUES (478366,6,62);
INSERT INTO mytable(AssesmentID,CategoryID,Value) VALUES (478366,24,0);
INSERT INTO mytable(AssesmentID,CategoryID,Value) VALUES (478366,59,62);
INSERT INTO mytable(AssesmentID,CategoryID,Value) VALUES (478366,60,0);
INSERT INTO mytable(AssesmentID,CategoryID,Value) VALUES (478366,61,62);
INSERT INTO mytable(AssesmentID,CategoryID,Value) VALUES (478366,64,0);
INSERT INTO mytable(AssesmentID,CategoryID,Value) VALUES (478366,65,62);
INSERT INTO mytable(AssesmentID,CategoryID,Value) VALUES (478366,66,12);
INSERT INTO mytable(AssesmentID,CategoryID,Value) VALUES (478366,67,0);
INSERT INTO mytable(AssesmentID,CategoryID,Value) VALUES (478366,68,12);
```

There are now new CategoryIDs. But only 6 of them. There is the following correlation between New and Old ID:

[image: correlation]

This means that for the new category 11 I should look at categoryid 67 and 68 and copy the entire row of the category with the maximum value in Value. So for 11 that would be  category 68. But I obviously need to change the categoryID to the new id which is 11.

Expected Result (hopefully with no mistake) would be:

```
+-------------+------------+-------+
| AssesmentID | CategoryID | Value |
+-------------+------------+-------+
|      478366 |         11 |    12 |
|      478366 |        548 |    62 |
|      478366 |        841 |    62 |
|      478366 |        842 |     0 |
|      478366 |        843 |    62 |
|      478366 |        840 |     0 |
+-------------+------------+-------+
```

There are too things to take into account:

First: Not all Old CategoryIds are always present. In the case no correlated Old CategoyID present we take an entry with a 0 as value (still the whole row with all 20 columns).

Second: for new Category 840 there is never a correlated category. So we do the same as we did in First.

After we are done we delete all the entries with the old category ids.

I tried something like this for category 11:

```
SELECT #SmallTable.*    
FROM #SmallTable
     INNER JOIN (SELECT CategoryID, max(ExpValue) as ExpValue 
                 FROM #SmallTable 
                 WHERE  CategoryID=67 or CategoryID=68
                ) AS Temp ON Temp.CategoryID= #SmallTable.CategoryID
WHERE #SmallTable.CategoryID=67 or #SmallTable.CategoryId=68;
```

But I got this error:

> Column '#SmallTable.CategoryID' is invalid in the select list because
>   it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

And I also feel like this is a bad way.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It has crazy things like: No images of data. Show your attempt at solving the problem. Explain what doesn't work. Ask a _specific_ question.

Comment: Thanks. I will adjust the main question to fit the guide better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your data and the expected results please consider the following.

I would also mention that you have a 0 for New CategoryID of 842, but following the rules you listed it would be a value of 62.  Not sure how you came to get 0 for this.

```
CREATE TABLE #mytable(
   AssesmentID INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,CategoryID  INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Value       INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #mytable(AssesmentID,CategoryID,Value) VALUES (478366,1,62);
INSERT INTO #mytable(AssesmentID,CategoryID,Value) VALUES (478366,2,30);
INSERT INTO #mytable(AssesmentID,CategoryID,Value) VALUES (478366,6,62);
INSERT INTO #mytable(AssesmentID,CategoryID,Value) VALUES (478366,24,0);
INSERT INTO #mytable(AssesmentID,CategoryID,Value) VALUES (478366,59,62);
INSERT INTO #mytable(AssesmentID,CategoryID,Value) VALUES (478366,60,0);
INSERT INTO #mytable(AssesmentID,CategoryID,Value) VALUES (478366,61,62);
INSERT INTO #mytable(AssesmentID,CategoryID,Value) VALUES (478366,64,0);
INSERT INTO #mytable(AssesmentID,CategoryID,Value) VALUES (478366,65,62);
INSERT INTO #mytable(AssesmentID,CategoryID,Value) VALUES (478366,66,12);
INSERT INTO #mytable(AssesmentID,CategoryID,Value) VALUES (478366,67,0);
INSERT INTO #mytable(AssesmentID,CategoryID,Value) VALUES (478366,68,12);


CREATE TABLE #NewCat (NewCatID int, OldCatID int NULL)
INSERT INTO #NewCat VALUES
    (11,67),
    (11,68),
    (548,65),
    (548,66),
    (841,2),
    (841,61),
    (841,64),
    (842,1),
    (842,24),
    (842,60),
    (843,6),
    (843,59),
    (840,NULL)


SELECT t2.AssesmentID, NewCatID,MAX(Value) Value
    FROM #NewCat t1
    INNER JOIN #mytable t2 on t1.OldCatID = t2.CategoryID
    GROUP BY t2.AssesmentID, NewCatID

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT t1.AssesmentID, JT.NewCatID,0 as [VALUE]
    FROM #mytable t1
    CROSS APPLY ( SELECT t1.NewCatID fROM #NewCat t1
                    LEFT JOIN #mytable t2 on t1.OldCatID = t2.CategoryID
                    WHERE t2.CategoryID IS NULL) JT
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped me. I found a little bit of a different way myself. But as far as i understand the core is the same. Just getting the top value out of the correlated values.